# OpenGL, rotating the piece of an object

Tags: opengl, glut

I have loaded a helicopter .obj file, it can move with keys(wasd) and (o - up)(l - down). Now I want to rotate the propeller while moving, but can't do this. [This is the link to .obj file.](https://www.dropbox.com/s/h9b7byh5bheqcqj/havoc.obj)

Any answer is appreciated.

This is my code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cmath>
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include <GL/GL.H>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>


using namespace std;
float v[27982][3];
int f[25130][3];
int mX, mY;
int trX, trY, trZ;

GLfloat amblight[] = { 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 };
GLfloat diflight[] = { 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0 };
GLfloat speclight[] = { 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0 };
GLfloat position[] = { 1.0, 0.0, 1.0 };
GLfloat difposition[] = { 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0 };

GLfloat shinines[] = { 120.0 };
GLfloat ambmatherial[] = { 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 };
GLfloat difmatherial[] = { 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0 };
GLfloat specmatherial[] = { 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0 };
GLfloat angle = 0.0;

void init() {
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);

    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, difposition);
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_DIFFUSE, diflight);
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_DIFFUSE, difmatherial);

    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_SPECULAR, speclight);
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_SPECULAR, specmatherial);
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_SHININESS, shinines);

}
void idle() {
    glutPostRedisplay();
}
class Coord
{
public:
    float x;
    float y;
    float z;
} a3d, b3d, c3d, original;


Coord norm(Coord a3d, Coord b3d, Coord c3d)
{
    Coord d3D_1, d3D_2, cross;
    d3D_1.x = b3d.x - a3d.x;
    d3D_1.y = b3d.y - a3d.y;
    d3D_1.z = b3d.z - a3d.z;

    d3D_2.x = c3d.x - b3d.x;
    d3D_2.y = c3d.y - b3d.y;
    d3D_2.z = c3d.z - b3d.z;

    cross.x = d3D_1.y * d3D_2.z - d3D_1.z * d3D_2.y;
    cross.y = d3D_1.z * d3D_2.x - d3D_1.x * d3D_2.z;
    cross.z = d3D_1.x * d3D_2.y - d3D_1.y * d3D_2.x;
    double l;

    l = sqrt(cross.x * cross.x + cross.y * cross.y + cross.z * cross.z);
    cross.x /= l;
    cross.y /= l;
    cross.z /= l;
    return cross;
}

void drawHelicopter(){

    glPushMatrix();
    for (int i = 0; i<25130; i++){
        glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
        a3d.x = v[f[i][0]][0];
        a3d.y = v[f[i][0]][1];
        a3d.z = v[f[i][0]][2];
        b3d.x = v[f[i][1]][0];
        b3d.y = v[f[i][1]][1];
        b3d.z = v[f[i][1]][2];
        c3d.x = v[f[i][2]][0];
        c3d.y = v[f[i][2]][1];
        c3d.z = v[f[i][2]][2];

        glVertex3f(a3d.x, a3d.y, a3d.z);
        glVertex3f(b3d.x, b3d.y, b3d.z);
        glVertex3f(c3d.x, c3d.y, c3d.z);
        Coord response = norm(a3d, b3d, c3d);
        glNormal3f(response.x, response.y, response.z);
        glEnd();
    }
    glPopMatrix();
}

void display(){

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);

    glLoadIdentity();

    glTranslatef(0, 0, -1500); 
    glRotatef(180.0, 0, 1, 0); 

    glTranslatef(trX, trY, trZ);
    glRotatef(mX, 0, 1, 0);
    glRotatef(mY, 1, 0, 0);

    glScalef(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    drawHelicopter();


    glutSwapBuffers();
}

void reshape(int w, int h){
    glViewport(0, 0, (GLsizei)w, (GLsizei)h);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluPerspective(60.0, (GLdouble)w / (GLdouble)h, 1.0, 8000.0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
}

void keyPressed(unsigned char key, int x, int y) {
    if (key == 'a'){ trX += 20; }
    else if (key == 'd'){ trX -= 20; }
    else if (key == 'w'){ trZ += 20; }
    else if (key == 's'){ trZ -= 20; }
    else if (key == 'o'){ trY += 20; }
    else if (key == 'l'){ trY -= 20; }
    glutPostRedisplay();
}

void mouse(int x, int y){
    mX = x;
    mY = y;
    glutPostRedisplay();
}

int main(){
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DEPTH);
    glutInitWindowPosition(0, 0);
    glutInitWindowSize(1200, 640);
    glutCreateWindow("Helicopter");
    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    int k = 0, m = 0;
    char ch;
    float aa, bb, cc;

    ifstream in("havoc.obj", ios::in);

    string line;
    while (getline(in, line))
    {
        //check v for vertices
        if (line.substr(0, 2) == "v ")
        {
            istringstream vert(line.substr(2));

            vert >> aa;
            vert >> bb;
            vert >> cc;
            v[k][0] = (float)aa;
            v[k][1] = (float)bb;
            v[k][2] = (float)cc;

            k++;
        }

        else if (line.substr(0, 2) == "f ")
        {
            int a, b, c, d; //to store mesh index
            int A, B, C, D; //to store texture index
            int a1, b1, c1;

            const char* chh = line.c_str();
            sscanf(chh, "f %i/%i/%i %i/%i/%i %i/%i/%i", &a, &A, &a1, &b, &B, &b1, &c, &C, &c1); //here it read the line start with f and store the corresponding values in the variables

            f[m][0] = a - 1;
            f[m][1] = b - 1;
            f[m][2] = c - 1;
            m++;
        }
    }
    printf("Use 'w'/'s' keys to move forward/downward\n");
    printf("Use 'a'/'d' keys to move to the left/right\n");
    printf("Use 'o'/'l' keys to move up/down\n");
    init();
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutReshapeFunc(reshape);
    glutKeyboardFunc(keyPressed);
    glutMotionFunc(mouse);
    glutIdleFunc(idle);
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: first of all you should have access to that particular geometry.. open gl can rotate the geometry.. but you will have to write your own logic.. there is no straight forward way of doing this.. best way is to load helicopter fan and rest of body seperately and combine them in your program

Comment: Well, but how to combine them?

Comment: than is basic drawing, put the propellar over body in code !

Comment: Yeah right, and is there anything to do with glPushMatrix() and glPopMatrix()?

Comment: yes you will need to use them as appropriate... for rotation of fan independent of body.

Comment: If maybe you could show any example, I would have a basic idea to do it. I can't imagine how can I use glRotatef for a fan and simultaneously glTranslatef for the whole object. Thank you

Comment: I dont have any example in hand but you can look at basic solar system examples. Its more or less same as moon rotating around earth while earth is rotating around sun.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the problem you are having is a common one that I'm sure many people looking at 3D graphics and animation have had at some point. You have a model that you are loading in with your obj file but you only want to rotate the propeller of the helicopter. So as soon as I read this a few things pop into my mind, loading the geometry separately, and also putting the geometry into a tree structure.

So imagine your different components of your helicopter as different nodes of a tree, for example, lets say we have a person. The torso will be the root node, the children would be the arms, legs, and neck, and each of those nodes children would move progressively further down until all points have been stored.

Now a helicopter is much simpler because there is much less going on at this point, just a propeller and the frame of the helicopter. You could implement a tree structure like this as it will be handy if you want to move to more complex animations and more complex objects.

Each tree node will contain the current properties of that node, this also helps fix some other problems but we will get to that soon. So for each node, you will store the rotations and translations in the nodes model space. And then you will propagate those values down your tree. So this way if your entire model rotates, your root node would rotate and propagate its rotation down the tree, so that the propeller rotates with the body of the helicopter and than also performs its own rotations that belong to its node. The same principal would apply to translations, just remember to get the ordering right otherwise you would see problems with your rotations not behaving correctly.

Finally, the end solution to your problem would be to split your actual model geometry into different objects in your 3D modelling program and load them as a different object in your code, they will all still be compiled into the same obj file though. You can then use this information to build your object tree.

I really hope this helps give you some sort of direction. =)

Comment: OBJ files can have group name (`g`) and object name (`o`) tags. If the file the poster uses has appropriate object/group definitions, it should be possible to use that information when reading the file, and later apply transformations to just specific objects/groups.

Comment: Thanks I didn't know this, just read up a bit on it now :) I've edited my answer :)